# Query Public Data Sets in Big Query using Python Pycharm

Tags: python, google-bigquery, bigdata

I want to retrieve data from Google big query. But user authentication is not happening for me. This is the message I am getting.

> "Access Denied: Project bigquery-public-data: The user sajith-sudhi@adroit-marking-183823.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project bigquery-public-data"

Here is the code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'NYCTaxi-c81bd00c9864.json')
project_id = 'bigquery-public-data'
client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)

query_job = client.query("""
  SELECT *
  FROM new_york.tlc_yellow_trips_2016
  LIMIT 1000""")
results = query_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

In below line you should set your own project

```
project_id = 'bigquery-public-data'
```

so it will be as

```
project_id = 'your_project'
```

And in query itself you shoud add project as below

```
query_job = client.query("""
  SELECT *
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york.tlc_yellow_trips_2016`
  LIMIT 1000""")
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\Sajith\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\_http.py", line 293, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/nyctaxi/jobs: Not found: Project nyctaxi

Comment: is `nyctaxi` you project name? it looks more like possible dataset name to me

Comment: it is project name - Project info
Project name
NYCTaxi
Project ID
adroit-marking-183823
Project number
516454577864

Comment: use `adroit-marking-183823` instead :o) The project name `NYCTaxi` is just friendly name for you to identify within your environment

Comment: Thank you. but now back to the original issue. Access Denied: Project adroit-marking-183823: The user sajith-sudhi@adroit-marking-183823.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project adroit-marking-183823.

Comment: Do i have to change anything in the Profile ?

Comment: that's not anymore an original issue! you need to make sure that whatever user you use  - has appropriate permissions - if you are the owner of this project - just open IAM and make it happen